# Roofer or framer that installs a Velux Sun Tunnel?

Tags: framing, carpentry, roofing

Who normally installs a Velux Sun tunnel in a new construction of a house?  Roofer or Framer?  Half the project is done on the roof and the other half in the house? 
Thx.
(yes, I know there are special Velux installers, but that isn't what I'd like to know).

Answer (score 1):

A roofer can/could install the tunnel, but I would leave to a finish carpenter to trim out the ceiling unless it has a fool proof way for it to finish out that a DIY or roofer could complete.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the roofer to be responsible for the watertight integrity of the sun tunnel penetrating the roof, proper flashing, etc.  Jack's comments are dead on.  Most roofers aren't very good interior finish carpenters.